# Possible duplicate - Exact Duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicates, close-reasons

This might be a duplicate but:

When a question is closed for being a possible duplicate it adds an automatic header

[image]

But in the closing explanation, we also have:

[image]

Is there any difference between being a possible duplicate and an exact duplicate? It's certainly not a big deal and I can suspect that users with loads of points might see a lot of tiny details that are invisible to others.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70758/wording-of-possible-exact-duplicates-when-closing-the-question and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87104/closed-as-an-exact-duplicate-possible-duplicate on [metase].

Comment: @doncherry I am even more confused now. That logic does not make any sense to me. But anyway, it's not a big deal. We can close this one too. Or should I delete it?

Comment: I think I once understood the reasoning, but right now it's not quite clear to me either. I don't know if we should or even can close this question. We definitely shouldn't delete it; it's useful to have the pointer to [metase] and there are probably more people wondering about the same thing as you.

Comment: @doncherry Then please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This truly confusing wording has been discussed on meta.stackoverflow.com, which serves as a meta site for all the stackexchange sites. I think I once understood the point behind it, but apparently not always. See for yourselves:

[Wording of “possible/exact duplicates” when closing the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70758/162565)
and
[Closed as an exact duplicate … Possible Duplicate [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87104/162565)

Comment: The first meta.SO question you're citing discusses a related but different issue. I'm not exactly sure if I understand the second linked question.